# Spring + Hibernate + JPA + 2 databases. persist silently fails to commits with @Transactional annotation

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-mvc, spring-transactions

My setup is Spring MVC 3.1, Hibernate 4.1 with two databases.

**My service methods seem to work fine for reads (for both dbs). But the persist fails to insert the data in the db - and no exception in the logs at all**. Looking at the sql output of hibernate it looks like it did retrieve the newly generated id but then never did the insert - if it did it doesn't show in the db nor was an insert logged in the log file. In the db I can see the sequence number is incremented but no data was inserted. I couldn't figure out what is wrong with my config. Hopefully someone has an idea.

Below are the relevant pieces from config file

```
    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    </bean>

    <bean id="mgrFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="xxx.yyy" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="puOne"/>
        <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="txMgr"/>
    <bean id="txMgr"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="mgrFactory">
    </bean>
```

This works fine as it is. What I want to do now is add the ability to use another database. So I added another data source, entity manager factory and transaction manager

```
    <bean id="dataSourceTwo" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
    </bean>

    <bean id="mgrFactoryTwo"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
          p:dataSource-ref="dataSourceTwo">
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="xxx.zzz" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="puTwo"/>
        <property name="persistenceProviderClass" value="org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence"/>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="txMgrTwo"/>
    <bean id="txMgrTwo"
          class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
          p:entityManagerFactory-ref="mgrFactoryTwo">
    </bean>
```

I also made sure that the two respective base DAOs annotate their entity manager's with the unit name like

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "puOne")
protected EntityManager entityManager;
```

The last thing I did was to add the transaction manager names inside my @Transactional annotations inside my services like

```
@Override
@Transactional(value="txMgrTwo"  propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public boolean create(User user) {
    userDao.persist(user);
}
```

Comment: try removing mode="aspectj" from tx:annotation-driven (maybe aspectj isn't be configured correctly). Also put a break point on the method and make sure you are seeing transactional interceptors.

Comment: thanks for the pointer Allen. I did a bit of debugging and it looks like the first transaction manager gets used inside the aspect irrespective of what value is specified inside the @Transactional annotation. I am starting to think may be JpaTransacitonManager is not the right class to use when you have multiple transactions